# How to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of this boundary value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

I want to find eigenvalue and eigenfunction of this problem:
$$
y''+ \lambda y=0, 0<x<l \\
y(0)=0, ly'(l)+ky(l)=0
$$
And $y'$ stands for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and similar for $y''$.

I get the following results:
After solving this homogeneous ODE,
$$
y=C_1 \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x) + C_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)\\
y(0)=0 \implies  C_1=0\\
\therefore y=C_2 \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x)\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\; y'=C_2 \sqrt{\lambda} \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x)\\
ly'(l)+ky(l)=0 \implies C_2 \bigg( l \sqrt{\lambda} \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}l) + k \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}l) \bigg)=0
$$
For non-trivial solution
$$
\bigg( l \sqrt{\lambda} \cos(\sqrt{\lambda}l) + k \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}l) \bigg)=0
$$

Now, I do not think any $\lambda$ satisfying the above equation. Can someone comment?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity let me call $\lambda=\mu^2$. The equation for the eigenvalues can be written as
$$
\mu=-\frac{k}{\ell}\tan(\ell\,\mu).
$$
$\mu=0$ is a solution that gives$y\equiv0$, so it is not an eigenvalue. If you draw the graph of $\mu$ and $-(k/\ell)\tan(\ell\,\mu)$, it becomes cleat that there is a solution
$$
\mu_k\in\Bigl(\frac{(2\,k-1)\,\pi}{2\,\ell},\frac{(2\,k+1)\,\pi}{2\,\ell}\Bigr),\quad k=1,2,3\dots
$$
To find the numerical values of $\mu_k$ you will have to resort to numerical methods. From the picture is also clear that
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\mu_k-\frac{(2\,k-1)\,\pi}{2\,\ell}=0.
$$